# Multiple records with same reference but different statuses, need SQL query to return specific results

Tags: sql, sql-server

First of all I am a bit of a SQL newbie and been learning on the job. 
I have a data set similar to the table below and want to create a SQL query to return only the items which have been ordered but not delivered.

```
Ref |   Country |   Ordered     |   Delivered
UPC1    |   AR  |   01/01/2010  |   02/01/2010
UPC1    |   BR  |   01/01/2010  |   02/01/2010
UPC1    |   FR  |   01/01/2010  |   
UPC1    |   UK  |   01/01/2010  |   02/01/2010
UPC1    |   US  |   01/01/2010  |   02/01/2010
UPC2    |   AR  |           |   
UPC2    |   BR  |           |   
UPC3    |   AR  |   01/03/2010  |   
UPC3    |   BR  |   01/03/2010  |   
UPC3    |   DE  |   01/03/2010  |   
UPC3    |   FR  |   01/03/2010  |   
UPC4    |   AR  |   01/01/2010  |   02/01/2010
UPC4    |   BR  |   01/01/2010  |   02/01/2010
UPC4    |   DE  |   01/01/2010  |   
UPC4    |   FR  |   01/01/2010  |   02/01/2010
UPC5    |   AR  |   01/03/2010  |   02/03/2010
UPC5    |   BR  |   01/03/2010  |   02/03/2010
UPC5    |   DE  |   01/03/2010  |   02/03/2010
UPC5    |   FR  |   01/03/2010  |   02/03/2010
UPC6    |   AR  |   01/03/2010  |   
UPC6    |   BR  |   01/03/2010  |   
UPC6    |   DE  |   01/03/2010  |   
UPC6    |   FR  |   01/03/2010  |
```

Sorry a newbie to posting as well so I don't know how to get the columns to display correctly. The data should paste into Excel or note pad in columns.

I have tried the following: 
select * 
from table 
where ordered <> '' 
and delivered = '' 
This returns the records which haven't been ordered but I need to see the records which have not been ordered at all in any country.

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried the following: select * from table where ordered <> '' and delivered = ''. This returns the records which haven't been ordered but I need to see the records which have not been ordered at all.

Comment: Put what you tried into the body of the question, please.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable
              WHERE Ordered <> ''
              AND Ref = T.Ref)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable
               WHERE Delivered <> ''
               AND Ref = T.Ref)
```

This will give you all records that have a product in REF which has been ordered somewhere but not delivered anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm having a little trouble implementing it. I don't understand what I substitute "Ref" with. This what I have: SELECT *
FROM dsc.DeliveryHistory T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dsc.DeliveryHistory
              WHERE FirstOrderDate <> ''
              AND Ref = T.Ref)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dsc.DeliveryHistory
               WHERE FirstDeliveryDate <> ''
               AND Ref = T.Ref)

Comment: Yes that looks accurate.  `Ref` is the column name you gave us in your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you can try

```
SELECT DISTINCT * from <table> 
WHERE Ordered IS NOT NULL AND Delivered IS  NULL
```